# Having an issue with accessing SampleSpringMaven Reason Service Unavailable

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Starting to learn Spring MVC dynamic web project with Maven and make it support Eclipse IDE with a simple hello world example but running into issues when I try to run on server. I get the below error:

```
Problem accessing /SampleSpringMaven/. Reason Service Unavailable
```

Here is my console:

Starting preview server on port 8080

```
Modules:
  SampleSpringMaven (null)
  SampleSpringMaven (/SampleSpringMaven)

2014-04-22 11:51:49.441:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.10.v20130312
2014-04-22 11:51:49.989:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{null,file:/C:/Users/mlim/Eclipse/Test/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/SampleSpringMaven/},C:/Users/mlim/Eclipse/Test/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/SampleSpringMaven
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null contextPath
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
2014-04-22 11:51:50.493:INFO:/SampleSpringMaven:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 22, 2014 11:51:50 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Apr 22, 2014 11:51:50 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Apr 22 11:51:50 EDT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 22, 2014 11:51:50 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Apr 22, 2014 11:51:51 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@29871db1: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Apr 22, 2014 11:51:51 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 570 ms
2014-04-22 11:51:51.155:INFO:/SampleSpringMaven:Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
Apr 22, 2014 11:51:51 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
Apr 22, 2014 11:51:51 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Apr 22 11:51:51 EDT 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Apr 22, 2014 11:51:51 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Apr 22, 2014 11:51:51 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@11846d13: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@29871db1
Apr 22, 2014 11:51:51 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 459 ms
2014-04-22 11:51:51.727:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

and web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
    version="2.5">  

    <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name>  

    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  

    <context-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>  
    </context-param>  

    <listener>  
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
    </listener>  
</web-app>
```

and jsp file:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>  
<title>Being Java Guys | Hello World</title>  
</head>  
<body>  

    <center>  
        <h2>Being Java Guys | Hello World</h2>  
        <h4>${message}</h4>  
    </center>  
</body>  
</html>
```

and pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">  
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  
    <groupId>com.beingjavaguys.sample</groupId>  
    <artifactId>SampleSpringMaven</artifactId>  
    <packaging>war</packaging>  
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>  
    <name>SampleSpringMaven Maven Webapp</name>  
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  

    <properties>  
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>  
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>  
    </properties>  

    <dependencies>  

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
            <version>${spring.version}</version>  
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>  
            <version>${spring.version}</version>  
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>  
            <version>${spring.version}</version>  
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>  
            <groupId>junit</groupId>  
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>  
            <version>3.8.1</version>  
            <scope>test</scope>  
        </dependency>  
    </dependencies>  

    <build>  
        <finalName>SampleSpringMaven</finalName>  
        <plugins>  
            <plugin>  
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
                <version>2.1</version>  
                <configuration>  
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>  
                    <server>my-tomcat</server>  
                    <path>/SampleSpringMaven</path>  
                </configuration>  
            </plugin>  
            <plugin>  
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
                <version>3.0</version>  
                <configuration>  
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>  
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>  
                </configuration>  
            </plugin>  
        </plugins>  
    </build>  

</project>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you add POM file., at times the repos don't get downloaded properly, you might need to delete the existing repos and Update the maven project to download the dependecies again.

Here is the basic POM you can start with.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.beingjavaguys.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleSpringMaven</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SampleSpringMaven Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SampleSpringMaven</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>my-tomcat</server>
                    <path>/SampleSpringMaven</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

You could also look into this it has the basic stuff to get started with Spring.

```
http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/08/spring-maven-web-application-in-eclipse.html
```

Comment: Hello - I do have a pom file, i updated my question to include mine